# Webpack - Cannot read property 'entryOption' of undefined

Tags: webpack

I did not change anything in my code/webpack config since yesterday. Everything was working fine, today I get the following error in my webpack build. I didn't find any info on this error. Already tried updagrading/downgrading packages but with no succcess.
I'm using webpack 3.8.1 and webpack-dev-server 3.1.11.

> Cannot read property 'entryOption' of undefined

```
const sharedConfig = require('./webpack.config.shared.js');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const eslintFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const paths = require('./paths');

const publicPath = '/';
const publicUrl = '';
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    require.resolve('./polyfills'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    paths.appIndexJs,
  ],
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: publicPath,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean)
    ),
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.mjs', '.js', '.json', '.web.jsx', '.jsx'],
    alias: sharedConfig.alias,
    plugins: [
      new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,
    rules: [
        {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: eslintFormatter,
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: paths.appSrc,
      },
      {
        oneOf: [
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true,
            },
          },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },

          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/css')],
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader', // compiles Sass to CSS
              },
            ],
          },

          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            include: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')],
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader', // creates style nodes from JS strings
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader', // translates CSS into CommonJS
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                  localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
                  importLoaders: 1,
                },
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
              },
              {
                loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                options: {
                  resources: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/css/_variables.scss'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/css/bootstrap/_variables.scss'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/css/material-kit/_variables.scss'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/css/material-kit/_variables_bootstrap.scss'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/css/bootstrap/mixins/_vendor-prefixes.scss'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/css/_mixins.scss'),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },

          {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            exclude: [/font-awesome/, /ellipse/, /price-up/, /price-down/, /carret-down/, /arrow-right-2/, /get-notified/, /switch/],
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
              },
              {
                loader: 'react-svg-loader',
                options: {
                  jsx: true, // true outputs JSX tags
                },
              },
            ],
          },
         {
            exclude: [/\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(env.raw),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
  ],
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
};
```

Comment: Did u find a solution for this?

Comment: @ChaitanyaAtkuri I had do update webpack to version 4.x.x and update webpack related packages

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your webpack-dev-server version to `3.0.0`(not `^3.0.0`). Please visit [this answer](https://github.com/cascornelissen/svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin/issues/25).